# Better Exposed Filters. How to put slider filter into a collapsible fieldset?

Tags: javascript, views, forms

the module allows you to wrap in fieldset checkboxes, but you can't wrap the slider, why?
how to overcome it?

Comment: Why can't you wrap slider? What happens when you try?

Comment: or may be JavaScript error

Comment: In the control settings BEF select-field has a checkbox to enable fieldset, but the field with the slider not.